# Leaflet - _map.setView([500,300], 3); - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm wondering why `_map.setView([500,300], 3);` doesn't place the map at position 500px, 300px as it should (I think?).

I tried to paste the code in this message but it cut of some code. So I placed the code at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/G8CqhLqd).

Comment: Leaflet requires a `LatLng` as first argument for `setView` - See reference here: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setview

Comment: Thanks for the help! It took a while to understand how to get LatLng and how to load it. But now it works! Thanks!

Comment: One more question. Do you know how to get LatLng from a tile image programmatically?

Comment: console.log(e.latlng);       gives cordinates of a click. But i need it from a tile image. Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide some code so the community can understand what you need.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0GR6XT6n This code shows latitude and longitude on rightclick. But i want to be able to programmatically get latitude and longitude from a tileLayer. Every tileLayer has a tileSize of 100 (100x100px) and a way would to be able to give a id or name for every tileLayer and then in some way get lat and lng from that tilelayer. I don't know how it would work programmatically. That was just something i thought of! Thanks

Comment: The `TileLayer` doc on LeafLet does not provide events for mouse interaction, try to open a new question and explain why you need this feature: someone could suggest you a different way to achieve your goal.